# Error when attempting to add an autocomplete field to the AuthUserGroupsAdmin

Tags: django-admin, django-authentication, django-users

I am attempting to add the default AuthUserGroups as a model to the admin page. It works fine, only I am trying to add an autocomplete field to the user section. When I put it, it gives an error "NoReverseMatch at /admin/Interface/authusergroups/add/"
"Reverse for 'Interface_authuser_autocomplete' not found. 'Interface_authuser_autocomplete' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

```py
class AuthUserGroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['group__name', 'user__username']
    autocomplete_fields = ['user']

admin.site.register(models.AuthUserGroups, AuthUserGroupsAdmin)
```

As a note, the error only comes up when attempting to add a new authUserGroup.

Is there any other way of implementing an autocomplete field within the AuthUserGroups Admin view, or is there a known solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Django by what field the `AuthUser` admin should be searchable in the autocomplete field. If you are using the default Django's admin you will need to unregister it and create a new UserAdmin for this use case.

```
@admin.site.register(AuthUser)
class AuthUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    search_fields = ['username']


@admin.site.register(AuthUserGroups)
class AuthUserGroupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['group__name', 'user__username']
    autocomplete_fields = ['user']
```